# How to migrate from PVC to VolumeClaimTemplate

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

There is a statefulset which uses a dynamic provisioner with storageclass name of `'some-class'`
and the following simple PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: example-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: some-class
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

`ReclaimPolicy` of the storageclass is `retain`.

When I delete the application the PV will be Retained.
But when reinstalling the App a new PVC and a new PV will be created and used. So I can't use the data from the old PV.

For this behaviour I need to use `volumeClaimTemplates` instead of `PVC`

The Question is how retain the data either by using the old PV or using the new one but data migrated from the old?

One solution would be to use `label-selector` for the PV from inside the claimtemplates, but unfortunately it doesn't work because of the dynamic provisioner.

Is there any Kubernetes level solution?
Or this is outside of the K8s capabilities and should be done by hand?

Comment: I'm not putting this as the answer because it's highly hypothetical but if you set the template to use "" as the storage class (i.e. no dynamic provisioning) and then manually rebind the existing PV to the new PVC, it should work, I think.

Comment: How are you "reinstalling app"? Are you deleting statefulset with it's PV and PVC and deploying a new one? [The PersistentVolumes associated with the Pods' PersistentVolume Claims are not deleted when the Pods, or StatefulSet are deleted](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-storage)